# How do I stop washer machine back flow when it it is on spin?

Tags: washing-machine, overflow

When I do a load of wash it all goes well until it drains. When it drains, it back flows.

I did every thing I could to snake and flush the drain. I even poured hot water down there and it still does that back flow.

What else can I do short of calling a plumber?

Comment: If by "back flow" you mean "sewage backup", then you need to look into all the "usual" pipe cleaning methods - chemicals (hot water by itself does very little), snaking, etc.

Comment: Pam, If you have snaked it and you can not reach the blockage then you need to see if there are clean out access ports elsewhere you can snake from. If you can not clear it you will need a plumber or someone with a longer snake, You can rent them at a tool rental shop. Are there drain issues with other fixtures in the house ?, snake from them as well.

Answer (score 0):

Backflow likely has nothing to do with a blocked drain, if that is truly what you're discussing. Backflow occurs when the pressure in the drain pipe is higher than that in the washer tub, causing waste water to flow backwards into the tub. The most likely causes are that the washer is not high enough relative to the drain pipe, and that there is [no air-break (AKA air gap)](https://inspectapedia.com/plumbing/1632s.jpg) in the drain pipe, required by many sanitation codes.

To fix the issue at little or no cost, do the following:

- Raise the height of the washing machine, e.g. by putting underneath it a *sturdy* 10 cm x 10 cm (4" x 4") frame, with depressions for the legs so they don't "walk" out during sPin cycle.
- Raise the height of the standpipe, the vertical pipe connected to the plumbing system.
- Add an [air gap](http://www.betterairgap.com/VA4-air-gap.html) between standpipe and drain hose, if there is not one present.

Comment: Hey, who are you to tell her washer not to _"walk" out during a sin cycle_??? :D (Too darn funny to edit!)

Comment: Ah! The dryer had been moved by *Freudian* slippage. And Freud also makes good tools. Mea culpa.

Comment: Well played, good sir. Well played!